# docker commitができない

Tags: docker

CentOS7でdockerを使用しています。

`docker commit`を実行しましたが、以下の様なエラーが出てイメージに出力できません。

```
$ docker commit testsys testsys
Error response from daemon: devmapper: Thin Pool has 145060 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 163840 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior
```

海外のサイトでは
`rm -rf /var/lib/docker`
を行えとかdockerを入れ直せという記事を見つけました。

現在のコンテナーに色々と設定をしているため、このコンテナーを消したくはないです。
どうやったらimagesを作れるかご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: dm-thinによるループバックデバイス（ディスク）の容量不足っぽいですね。詳しくないので、回答は書けませんが、コンテナが使っているディスク容量を拡張すれば良い気がします。ぐぐったら `dm.basesize` という設定項目で容量が決まるそうです。ご参考まで。

Answer (score 0):

不要なデータを削除してみてはどうでしょうか．
利用しているdockerのバージョンによりますが，
最新のdockerでは

```
docker system prune
```

コマンドを実行することで，停止しているコンテナやイメージ等を削除してくれます．

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: 残念ながらdocker: 'system' is not a docker command.との結果で、私が使用しているDocker version 1.12.6, build 96d83a5/1.12.6にはこのコマンドがないようです。docker ps -aやdocker imagesで不要なコンテナ・イメージは全て削除していると思います。今のコンテナは設定が多々入っているので落としたくはなく困りました。

Comment: dm.min_free_spacを増やすとdockerの再起動が必要だと思いますので、Create more free space in thin poolのやり方はご存知ないでしょうか？こちらもdockerプロセスの再起動が必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: sudo docker export <コンテナ名> > <ファイル名.tar>でコンテナをファイル出力できましたのでひとまずは大丈夫かと（思います）。dockerプロセスを再起動かけようかと思いますが、dm.min_free_spaceの設定方法がわかりません。どこかに記載しているという情報だけでもいいので、ご存知であればご教示お願いします。